# Prove a Set is a $\operatorname{range}(L)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> Suppose $L:V\to W$ is a linear mapping. Let $B=\{b_1,\ldots ,b_n\}$ be a spanning set for $V$. Prove $C=\{L(b_1),\ldots ,L(b_n)\}$ is a spanning set for $\operatorname{range}(L)$.

---

So I know that finding a range for $L$ is basically finding a spanning set. So for example if$$L\left (\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\\end{bmatrix}\right )=1$$then you're basically finding a spanning set for $1$. So by definition, the set $L(B)$ will be a spanning set for $\operatorname{range}(L)$. So how do I explain this in detail?

Answer (score 1):

To show something is a spanning set, you need to show that every vector $w$ in the range can be written as a linear combination of the vectors in $C$. I don’t think this is “by definition” as you say, so you may be missing something here. To prove the statement, you’ll need to use the properties of linear transformations.

Also, I don’t know what the spanning set for $1$ means. Do you mean the vector $[1]$ spans the range?